# Native transfer plugin - not available after install in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I have installed native TRANSFER plugin in my ionic 2 app in 2 steps:
1. ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
2. npm install --save @ionic-native/transfer

After that i imported the plugin in my   home.ts page.
    Import { Transfer } from '@ionic-native/transfer'

I tried to use the plugin to upload a file
    var ft = new Transfer();

But i can't use ft var, because Transfer plugin look like it's not avalable. 
If i write  ft.upload ()  i receive an error like: **Property 'upload' does not exist on type 'Transfer'**.

My technologies:
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4

In the previous version of my app when using **Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.5 /Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0**  all worked just fine.

Does anyone has any solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `3.1.0 version of Ionic Native`,
you have to use the plugin like a provider.

1. Import it in **app.module.ts** and set as provider

   ```
    import {Transfer} from '@ionic-native/transfer'

    @ngModule({
      //...
      providers:[
          Transfer,
          ..]
   ```
2. Inject in the component/provider where you need to use it.

   ```
   constructor(private fileTransfer:Transfer){}
   ```
3. Use the `fileTransfer` object.

Documentation: [Ionic Native](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/) and [Transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/)

Comment: is this wrong then or? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/

Comment: That is the second step.. but without setting as provider you get "no provider for" error

Comment: I mentioned the steps in general for Ionic native 3

Comment: any link for updating to native 3? I'm using old one yet.

Comment: you can compare your `package.json` with the [starter app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json). Also check the [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)