# Ionic2 and cordova-plugin-network-information

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am using Ionic2 rc4, and want to check the network connection. Following [this documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) and [this documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/), I install the plugins:

> ```
> $ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
> $ npm install --save @ionic-native/network
> ```

code

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    ...checkNetwork()();
});

public checkNetwork(): void {

    document.addEventListener("offline", this.offline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", this.online, false);

    Network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
        console.log('Network.type = ', Network.connection, Network.name);
        this.online();
    });

}

offline() {
    alert('offline');
}

online() {
    alert('online');
}
```

The `offline()` and `online()` functions, never get invoked.

UPDATE

`Network` is defined in `providers` in `app.modules.ts`.

Updating the code to:

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

constructor(public network: Network) 

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
        console.log('this.network.type = ', this.network);
        this.online();
    });
```

[image]

Comment: why you're still using buggy `Ionic2 rc4`?

Comment: I agree, I need to upgrade, will do but have been busy

Comment: what is the version of `ionic-native` are you having?

Comment: "ionic-native": "2.2.11",

Comment: do you also have "@ionic-native/core"?

Comment: Do any of you guys have a link with documentation to upgrade Ionic2 to the latest version?

Comment: "@ionic-native/core": "^3.2.4",

Comment: you can update your package.json as per the [starter app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: the docs have been updated for ionic native 3.x .. check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027467/native-transfer-plugin-not-available-after-install-in-ionic2/43027516#43027516) for using plugins in ionic native 3.x

Comment: Thanks guys, I will upgrade to the latest Ionic 2 and see what happns

Comment: I upgraded my `package.json` (see above). `ionic info` shows I am using `ionic 2.3.0` (`Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0`) now. But . still cannot get `ionic-native-network` to work. Do you suggest I use a different plugin?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027467/native-transfer-plugin-not-available-after-install-in-ionic2/43027516#43027516) @Richard

Comment: Thanks will have a look