# what is the difference between ionic-native and @ionic-native/xxx in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am attempting to use Ionic Native functionality in my Ionic2 application. I am finding a significant amount of examples and installation instructions for ionic-native node module and also for @ionic-native/[package-name]. I am unclear as to which node-module to use. It appears as though ionic-native comes installed, but, all of the documentation at https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ uses @ionic-native/[package-name]. What is the difference if any between these two packages? Which should be used in my ionic2 application?

Below is my current project info

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between 
**ionic-native v 2.x** and **ionic native v3.x**

**ionic-native v 2.x**
If this is the version, all cordova wrappers will be available in the particular package and the plugins are used as global objects imported directly from `ionic-native`.
[V2 readme](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/8cd648db5cddd7bdbe2bd78839b19c620cc8c04c/README.md).

**ionic native v3.x**
This is the current version (as of now 3.4.4).
You need to install `npm install @ionic-native/core` and then install the individual package.`@ionic-native/[package-name]`
For use you need to inject the plugin as a provider. Check [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43027516/4826457)